# ClickOnce deployment goes rogue after upgrading to .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, nuget, clickonce

I upgraded a project from .Net Framework 4.7.1 to .Net Framework 4.8, and **ClickOnce** stopped working. It deploys, but it is no longer generating all of the files, and it is no longer respecting the path of the content files. I appreciate any idea you may have to fix this issue, thanks in advance.

Here is the side by side comparison

[image]

### Sample repository to reproduce

[Here](https://github.com/cilerler/issue.microsoft_msbuild_5485) is a link for sample repositories.

### Initial steps

1. Open a `DeveloperCMD` or `Developer Powershell`
2. Change the location to the application folder's location.  For me, it is `cd ~\Source\github\cilerler\issue.microsoft_msbuild_5485`

### ProjectReference method

1. Run the command `MSBuild app.xml -p:BuildId=1` to generate initial output. It will produce a publish folder at `.\artifacts\publish`.

### PackageReference method

1. Run the command `MSBuild library.xml -p:BuildId=1` to generate version 0.0.0.1 of the NUPKG file.  It will place it in the folder at `.\artifacts\packages` which project is set up to look for as a local NuGet service.
2. Change the snippet below

   ```xml
   <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj">
     <Project>{705ccf76-2c45-43d3-a839-7591813b5522}</Project>
     <Name>ClassLibrary1</Name>
   </ProjectReference>
   ```

   with the snippet below

   ```xml
    <PackageReference Include="ClassLibrary1">
      <Version>0.0.0.1</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>analyzers;build</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
   ```

   in **ConsoleApp1.csproj**

### ClassLibrary.csproj

```xml
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Lookup\TextFile1.txt">
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <!-- <Link>Lookup\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link> -->
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ClearScript">
      <Version>6.0.2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>contentFiles;analyzers</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

### NuSpec file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ClassLibrary1</id>
    <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    <authors>DotNetDeveloper</authors>
    <owners>DotNetDeveloper</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ClearScript" version="6.0.2" exclude="Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="Microsoft.CSharp" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Core" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Net.Http" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml.Linq" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/net48/Lookup/TextFile1.txt" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

### Side notes

1. Don't forget to delete the cache from `~\.nuget\packages\classlibrary1` before you build the **ConsoleApp1.csproj** each time.

Comment: @MickyD, please do not remove the tag [tag:nuget]; the issue only occurs when things come from the NuGet.  If I create the file in the 2nd project, there is no issue.